# Android - how to draw 2-directional gradient?

Tags: android, gradient, shapes

I started playing with gradients and I've found it's pretty easy to draw 1-directional gradient (like from top to bottom, from left to right, or in diagonale...) but how to draw 2-directional gradient? I mean something like this:

[image]

Big blue rectangle it's 2-directional gradient - on top right corner there is blue and to the left its transforming to white and to the bottom it's transforming to the black. How to draw this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is: you must combine 2 different LinearGradients, for example:

```
LinearGradient val = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, height, Color.WHITE, Color.BLACK, TileMode.CLAMP);
                LinearGradient sat = new LinearGradient(0, 0, width, 0, Color.WHITE, Color.HSVToColor(hsvCopy), TileMode.CLAMP);
                ComposeShader merged = new ComposeShader(val, sat, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY)
```

;

And of course important:

```
[view with this background].setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

on phones with 3.0 android and higher

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this when you create your `gradient` color:

```
 <gradient
    android:centerColor="@color/my_white"
    android:startColor="@color/my_darker_gray"
    android:endColor="@color/my_darker_gray"
    android:angle="45"/>
```

Specify the color you desire for the `start/end/center` location of the `gradient`, and specify the angle of the color switching.

Comment: it's something different. I don't need gradient in 45 degree angle, I know how to do it. I need what I've said: 2-directional gradient, which means in my example that top right corner would be blue and to the left it would be transforming to white and to the bottom it would be transforming to the black

Comment: well I did not had experiance with this kind of gradient color. but you call look at this project source code to see how they did it:
https://code.google.com/p/color-picker-view/source/browse/trunk/src/afzkl/development/mColorPicker/views/ColorPickerView.java