# PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY inside ComposeShader doesn't work properly

Tags: android, ondraw, porter-duff

I want to implement color palette into my application. This is the main onDraw method.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        int h = canvas.getHeight();
        int w = canvas.getWidth();
        if (paint == null) {
            paint = new Paint();
            luar = new LinearGradient(0.f, 0.f, 0.f, h, 0xffffffff, 0xff000000, TileMode.CLAMP);
        }
        int rgb = Color.HSVToColor(color);
        Shader dalam = new LinearGradient(0.f, 0.f, w, 0.f, 0xffffffff, rgb, TileMode.CLAMP);
        ComposeShader shader = new ComposeShader( luar, dalam, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        paint.setShader(shader);
        canvas.drawRect(0.f, 0.f, w, h, paint);
    }
```

But, `ComposeShader shader` seems not working.

That is,

```
ComposeShader shader = new ComposeShader( dalam, luar, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

shows only vertical gradient. And if I change the parameters:

```
ComposeShader shader = new ComposeShader( luar, dalam,  PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

it shows horizontal gradient. No multiplication! Why?

Comment: see http://pastebin.com/y9sAMNAP

Comment: @pskink , this http://stackoverflow.com/q/15878769/1979882

Comment: @pskink , your link haven't helped

Comment: so whats the difference between my solution and the link you posted?

Comment: @pskink , the save behaviour: only the first gradient is show. They are not multiplied

Comment: so you didn't run my code then... you probably just ^C/^V parts of my code...

Comment: @pskink , i've tried:) the same incorrect behaviour

Comment: i have no idea how you tested that, but i run it on v4.4, v5 and v6 devices and it just works ok